# Is there a way to get metadata from Spring's task:scheduled-tasks?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Spring's [scheduled tasks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) using the xml format (specifically under 25.4.3 The 'scheduled-tasks' element)

Is there a way to get metadata such as "last execution time", "last complete time" from this task scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not that I know of. It'd surprise me though if it did as it's merely a thin layer over Java 5's executor service.

We once had similar requirements (finding out what time a scheduled task will run next) and ended up digging into `org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar` via reflection. Maybe this is a starting point.